How to optimize selectionManager.select(). Lags the system when selecting
My code has performance problems when selecting. It searches and returns the index very fast. I return the index to create createSelectionIdBuilder by index. but when it comes to the part of code that passes aelectionList into select() "selectionManager.select(selectionList, false); it slows down my system.
Is there any way I can fix this problem? Thanks.
const selectionList = []

    indices.forEach((index: number) => {
      const selection = selectionIdBuilder.createSelectionIdBuilder()
        .withTable(dataTableOrigin, index)
        .createSelectionId();
      selectionList.push(selection);
    })

    selectionManager.select(selectionList, false);

I expect when calling .select() of visual the app does not freeze
